# Ambiguous case in a inequality

Tags: inequality

I'm getting mad after noticing an anbiguous case in a inequality.

The track is: ***-3x+8<0***

So the first step is: ***-3x<-8***

But now, should I do ***3x>8*** or ***x<-8/-3***?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. When you multiply both sides of an inequality by a negative number, you need to reverse the sign. $-3x<-8\implies(-1)(-3x)>(-1)(-8)\implies3x>8\implies\boxed{x>8/3}$.

Comment: When you multiply by a *negative* number, that is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach
$$-3x+8\lt 0$$
$$8\lt 3x$$
$$\frac83\lt x$$
There's nothing wrong with having $x$ on the right-hand side.